# Is the basis of every subspace of a vector space a subset of the basis for the vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a  vector space with a basis $\beta$, and $W\subset V$ and subspace of $V$. Is there always a $\beta_{W} \subset \beta$ such that $\beta_{W}$ is a basis for $W$?

I have the feeling that it doesn't hold, but I'm having difficulty thinking of a counterexample. Can someone give a hint as to where I could find a good counterexample?

Comment: You can find a counterexample with $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, and the usual basis. Take as subspace $W$ the vectors $(x,x)$.

Comment: Wow this question has such a trivial counterexample and I didn't even see it. Thank you.

Comment: Every space $V$ of dimension $\gt 1$, and every basis of such a space, can be used in the same way to produce a counterexample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly not: For any field $\mathbb{F}$, consider the basis $((1, 0), (0, 1))$ of $\mathbb{F}^2$. Neither $(1, 0)$ nor $(0, 1)$ spans the subspace spanned by $(1, 1)$.